# Multiple Suppliers Rails Online Store

Tags: ruby-on-rails, e-commerce, spree

I need to create a store that allows multiple supplier to add products and manager orders. I'm currently looking at spree and spree_suppliers extension. I'm just wondering if any one has any advise or suggestions about this. Can maybe suggest alternative or better ways of achieving this.

Edit: I think [this](https://github.com/spree-contrib/spree_drop_ship) is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. [Spree Drop Ship](https://github.com/spree-contrib/spree_drop_ship) is what you most probably want.